# Check if it is last section fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

Im using [fullpage](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage) plugin in my website, this is my markup

```
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section section1">Some section</div>
  <div class="section section2">Some section</div>
  <div class="section section3">Some section</div>
  <div class="section section4">Last section</div>
</div>
```

In my website I want to do the following: User will scroll down section per section, when user reaches the last section I want to redirect the user to another page, how can I check that user is in last section in fullpage.js?

Comment: probably use **[`.afterLoad(anchorLink, index)`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterload-anchorlink-index)** callback, and check if this received `index` parameter is equal to the length of `$('#fullpage .section').length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I finally figured out, I checked the fullpage has some callbacks, so I used the `onLeave` callback, here is my code (in CoffeeScript)

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage
        onLeave: (index, nextIndex, direction) ->

            if index is 3 && direction is'down'
                #redirect the user to a new page.
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`afterLoad` function](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterload-anchorlink-index) in fullpage to achieve this. The following code snippet should give you an idea of how you can use `afterLoad` to check if the user is on the last section and do a redirect if so:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
        ...

        afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
            // Section indexes in fullpage start at 1
            if(index === $('#fullpage .section').length){
                window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
            }
        }

        ...
    });
```